# This Bash regex is allowing an unwanted alpha char through

Tags: regex, string, bash

The purpose is to allow users to input either a valid datetime string suitable for `date --date=`, or to enter -/+ number of days.  If the input is `[+-]?[0-9]+` (pseudo), then match, otherwise fail.

[edit] To clarify: the match is to further process -+days into a datetime for `date`.  An already valid datetime string should fail in order to avoid the `&& etc` that does more processing, which is why I'm testing for numerics only (won't match a datetime that must have ' ' or '-' or '/' embedded).

The regex is to allow (match) three scenarios:

- string starts with '-'
- string starts with '+'
- string contains nothing but numerics.

It should fail with input like "+a1".

`[[ "${DATETIME}" =~ ^(-|\+)?[0-9]+$ ]] &&  etc`

The result is that it incorrectly matches "a1", "-a1" and "+a1", but correctly fails on "+a", "aa1" or "1a" etc.

How is the single leading-or-amost-leading alpha char matching the regex?

Comment: It doesn't match them here. What Bash version are you using? The safest way is to put the regex in a variable and then use that variable (unquoted) inside of `[[ ]]`.

Comment: You should quote the regex.

Comment: @pyrocrasty Only if your Bash is 3.1 or older. For 3.2 or newer, quoting prevents interpretation as a regex. See, for example [BashGuide/Patterns](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns).

Comment: @BenjaminW. Oh, thanks, I didn't realize that. I don't use Bash much these days. Quoting still works in ZSH. (I'm surprised I haven't been bitten by that in scripts, though.) It must be a hassle having to remember everything you need to escape... although I guess that's why you suggested putting the regex in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Following Regex pattern should do:

```
^([+-]|[[:digit:]]+$)
```

- `^()` matches the enclosed grouped patterns at the start of the line (string)
- In the captured group `()`, `[+-]|[[:digit:]]+$` matches either `[+-]` or `[[:digit:]]+$` i.e. strings starting with `+` or `-` are matched, and strings that contain only numerics are matched

---

On a second thought, reading your question it does not seem very clear to me so i am leaving another solution, if you want to match strings that contain only numerics and can have `+` or `-` at start:

```
^[+-]?[[:digit:]]+$
```

If either `+` or `-` must be present:

```
^[+-][[:digit:]]+$
```

Comment: Thanks.  Isn't `^[+-]?[[:digit:]]+$` effectively the same as mine?  I'm still perplexed how it is letting an alpha through as the first char or as the second char if prepended by + or -.

Comment: @NickColeman No, `?` makes the preceding token optional, matches the preceding token 0 or 1 time, and you are making `-`/`+` optional.

Comment: @heemayl: which is exactly the same effect, no?

Comment: @NickColeman sorry I missed your edited comment....Yes, it is the same...